# Divide to n bins with minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

1. Consider `2*k` tuples (a0, b0), (a1, b1), ... and 2 bins A and B. placing the `i-th` tuple in bin `A` will cost you `ai` dollar, in bin `B` will cost you `bi` dollar. What the minimum cost to place `k` elements in bin A and `k` elements in bin B.

I came up with the greedy algorithm: sort the tuples array, taking `abs(ai - bi)` as key, in descending order. However, can we solve this problem by using dynamic programming? What if there are `n` bins instead of two.

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you explain how you used the sort result to fill the bins? And how that guarantees that the total cost is minimised?

Comment: Hint: Think bottom up. Think about filling the last bin it has to be either A or B. Lets assume its B. Then remaining tuples for B is k - 1, while remaining tuples for A is k. Or if it is A, the remaining for A is k - 1, remaining for B is k. So the minimum cost of filling the last bin is minimum of cost( k-1 tuples for B, k tuples for A ) + bi , cost( k tuples for B, k-1 tuples for A ) + ai , now think of recursively implementing and then memoize.

Comment: @trincot You use it by splitting that sorted list in half.  As for why it is best, take any other division.  Pull them out in no particular order to get an unsorted list.  Sort it with a bubble sort, keeping track of the division.  Every swap either leaves the cost alone (swapping within a bin) or lowers the cost (swapping across the bin boundary) until you stop at this one.  Therefore no other division can be better.

Comment: @SomeDude That's the top down approach, not the bottom up.  But I don't see offhand how to memoize it without doing something silly like memoizing all possible subsets.  (Memoizing an exponential amount of stuff is not a good idea.)

Comment: @btilly by "bottom up" I mean arrive at the finish from the start. So filling bin A with k tuples and bin B with k tuples requires first filling either k-1 tuples in B or A and k tuples in B or A. So get to the answer you work up from 2 bins to 2k bins. As for memoizing you need to memoize solution for i items in A and j items in B.

Comment: @SomeDude I understand what you meant, but the usual terminology for recursive+memoize is still "top-down".  As opposed to "bottom-up" where you build a table.  That said, I just figured out the DP solution, and you're right.

Comment: @btilly, thanks for your comment, but I was actually aiming for the OP to clarify their question. We can't know from his question what he did with the sorted result, and it seems relevant to mention it in the question.

Comment: @trincot We may not actually know, but there is only one obvious thing to do and it gives the right answer for `n=2`.  It doesn't give an answer by the requested technique, but it does give the right answer.

Comment: Indeed, but it should be in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `dp[i][j]` be minimum cost when put j element in bin A for the first i elements, e.g., `dp[0][0]` is the minimum cost to put 0 elements in A for the first 0 elements; `dp[4][2]` is the minimum cost to put 2 element in A for the first 4 elements

Then: For the `ith` element (index is `i - 1` so I use `b[i - 1]` and `a[i - 1]`), we need to put it in either bin A or bin B. So we calculate the min of two cases:

`dp function: dp[i][j] = Math.min(dp[i - 1][j] + b[i - 1], dp[i][j - 1] + a[i - 1])`

Then the problem is to get `dp[2*k][k]`

Comment: And a note about efficiency.  This is `O(k^2)`.  The natural generalization to `n` buckets will be `O(k^n)`.  For `n=2` the greedy method is better.